# Selenium Grid2 - run test on multiple nodes

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, parallel-processing, selenium-grid

From documentation and various forum posts, I found out that Grid2 is running tests in parallel only if you invoke that "parallelism" trough your test runner(if you have that option).
Which is kind of strange design decision, because if I want to run same tests on different nodes with different settings, there is two options:

-run one test multiple times which is not parallel

-clone that test, configure runner to run tests in parallel, for each of the cloned test define version and then get what I want - running same test on different machines in parallel

I was looking into a custom CapabilityMatcher solution, but that's just imposing new rules on matching, not what should happened when node is matched(look for more nodes or stop)

Does anybody know the way how to achieve parallelism that I need without cloning tests or running same test multiple times in order to hit all versions of the browser?

Thank you

Comment: In my particular case I'm writing tests on Python and using pytest framework. It allows me to create collections of tests without cloning them but using parametrization options provided by the framework.

Comment: ok, but how tests are running depends on how do you run your collection(in parallel, seqential)?

Comment: yes, it depends on test runner. If I understand you right, my approach solves your problem. What it does is "cloning" one test at the collection time so we actually get multiple equal tests with different parameters which can be launched one by one or in parallel. The parameter itself is the desired capabilities we need. The only problem I've encountered is that I can't parametrize setup method, so I had to move browser initialization to test methods

Comment: yes, that's better solution, unfortunately we are using mstest and that kind of choice for running same test with multiple parameters is not possible - it is run seqentually